# Border Bottom property doesn't appear at the place

Tags: html, css

I am just working in a small project of mine.

Here is the url http://jsfiddle.net/KpFj2/1/embedded/result/

```
               <article>
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <div class="comment"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>25 Feb 2013</div>
                    <div class="calender"><i class="icon-comment"></i>22 Comments</div>
                </div>
                <div class="post-content">
                    <h1>A New Beginning, A New Story</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. </p>
                </div>
           </article>
```

Now I just want one help I just wanted to know why the border bottom property doesn't go exactly where I wanted it to be ? It appears somewhere in the middle.

Can you please guide me to solve this error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some way to clear your floats. Add `overflow:hidden` to `#content article`

Comment: thanks @wex it helped and worked. But can you tell me why I had to give overflow:hidden to these items ? may be next time I won't have to ask then :)

Comment: If you float an element in a container, the container no longer wraps around that item. The only way to tell the container to wrap around the floated element is to [clear the float](http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101), either by using `clear: both` on an item following the floated element, or setting `overflow: hidden` to the container.

Answer (score 1):

You have floated the children Divs without clearing them.

There are a few options to fix it:

HTML

```
<article>
     <div class="entry-meta"></div>
     <div class="post-content"></div>
</article>
```

CSS

```
article { overflow: hidden; }
```

or

HTML

```
<article>
     <div class="entry-meta"></div>
     <div class="post-content"></div>
     <br class="clear" />
</article>
```

CSS

```
.clear { clear:both; }
```

Comment: You need to specify a width for the overflow:hidden trick to work, don't you? So, the CSS would be `article { overflow:hidden; width:100%; }` wouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry... my question was whether width has to be specified, be it by px, % or auto. Just wondered, because both you and Wex left out any width specification, and I wasn't sure if my information was out of date.

Comment: Well, width: auto is the default width for block level elements.  I've never run into a problem when width wasn't specifically set.

Comment: I'll have to take a look at some of the places I've worked with it, then, and remember that for the future! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

set  `position: absolute;` for `#content article` OR use `overflow:hidden;` and see.

Comment: I'd most certainly not advise that anyone use `position: absolute`, unless they are ready to deal with the consequences of taking the element out of the document flow.

Answer (score 1):

You're using HTML5 Boilerplate where a `.clearfix` helper class already exists to solve the problem described by @Wex and @JesseLee .

```
/*
 * Clearfix: contain floats
 *
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that receive the `clearfix` class.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

It was described in this post from N. Gallagher: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

You just have to add this class to your `article` element as in http://jsfiddle.net/KpFj2/2/